# Geometric Brownian Motion problem - Compute $\mathbb{P}(X_3 < 3)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, brownian-motion

> Suppose $X_t$ is Geometric Brownian motion with $\mu=1$, $\sigma^2=1$.
> Given $X_1=1$, find the probability of $X_3<3$.

Let's remember that we say that $X_t$ is a Geometric Brownian Motion if for all $t\geq0$

\begin{align}
X_t=e^{\left ( \mu - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} \right )t+\sigma W_{t}}
\end{align}

With $W_{t}$ a standard Brownian motion.

In our case, we have:

\begin{align}
X_t=e^{\frac{t}{2}+ W_{t}}
\end{align}

We also know that $X_3 - X_1 \sim N(0,2)$, and that $X_3-X_1$ is independent of $X_1$. We can express $X_3$ as

\begin{align}
X_3=(X_3 - X_1)+X_1
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_3<3)&=\mathbb{P}\left ( (X_3 - X_1)+X_1 < 3\right )
\end{align}

And,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_3<3|X_1=1)&=\mathbb{P}\left ( (X_3 - X_1)+X_1 < 3\right |X_1=1)\\&=\mathbb{P}\left ( (X_3 - X_1)+1 < 3\right |X_1=1)\\&=\mathbb{P}\left ( (X_3 - X_1)< 2\right |X_1=1)\\&=\mathbb{P}\left ( (X_3 - X_1)< 2\right)
\end{align}

Since, $X_3-X_1 \sim N(0,2)$. Then, $\mathbb{F}_{X_3-X_1}(2)=0.92$.

But it seems that my answer is wrong. Do you identify what is my mistake? Do you have any other hint to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We also know that $X_3 - X_1 \sim N(0,2)$, and that $X_3-X_1$ is independent of $X_1$.

This is completely incorrect.  It would be true if $X_t$ were were a Brownian motion, but it's not -- it's a Geometric Brownian motion.  For Geometric Brownian motion, the corresponding result is that $\dfrac{X_3}{X_1}$ is independent of $X_1$ and $\dfrac{X_3}{X_1}$ has the same distribution as $X_{3-1} = X_2$.

This gives
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(X_3<3|X_1=1) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_3}{X_1}<3\middle|X_1=1\right) \\ &= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_3}{X_1}<3\right) \\ &= \mathbb{P}(X_2<3) \\ &= \mathbb{P}(W_2 < \ln(3) - 1)\end{align*}$$
which you then can reference the $N(0,2)$ distribution to approximate.